# How to forbid activity to change orientation even when you enable the landscape setting in your mobile?

Tags: android, android-activity

I don't want an **Activity** to change **orientation** to **landscape** no matter what, even when you enable the landscape setting in your mobile.

***What should I do to achieve the goal?***

Comment: <activity
            android:name="com.liananse.activity.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"></activity>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Manifest file, under activity whose orientation you want to restrict, add:

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```